# Addition of numeric 0 value

Tags: r, numeric

Suppose x is a real number, or a vector. i is valued-False. Then x[i] will return numeric(0). I would like to treat this as a real number 0, or integer 0, which are both fit for addition.

numeric(0)+ any real number will return numeric(0), whereas I wish to obtain the real number being added as the result. What can I do to convert the numeric (0) value? Thanks in advance!

---

Edit: if a is numeric(0), b is real, use sum(a,b) to obtain sensible output.

Comment: off-topic. You'll need to use an `if` condition. But you probably refactor your code since this issue should not even occur.

Answer (score 2):

I am with @Roland in his comment, that code refactoring is probably the better solution, but for the sake of argument, you can write your own addition function:

```
`%myadd%` <- function(x, y){
  if(is.numeric(x) & length(x) == 0) 
    return(0 %myadd% y)
  if(is.numeric(y) & length(y) == 0)
    return(x %myadd% 0)
  x + y
}


8 %myadd%  2
8 %myadd% numeric(0)
numeric(0) %myadd% 5
numeric(0) %myadd% numeric(0)
```